# How to configure MySQL pid file permissions?

Tags: mysql, systemd

I know MySQLd will create a pid file as set up in mysqld.service:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

However, it creates the file with a `660` permission, meaning unprivileged users can't even read it. I wanted my user to be able to read it so as to check if the service is running (for my i3 statusbar). So far I've been able to do so with an `ExecStartPost` hook:

```
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/chmod a+r /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Yet I'm sure there must be some other way to configure that. After all, my other services and daemons generate more permissive pid files.

Comment: Can't your user run `systemctl status mysqld` to check if it is running?

Comment: for monitoring purposes it's better to check the process list and not rely on a file with a number inside (a pid file).  That number is no indication whether the process is running and if a process with such pid exists it may be some other process (e.g. if mysqld died some time ago and the pid file was not automatically removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1 write a cron script owned by the mysql user to write the output of "service mysqld status" to a text file which has read permissions set to allow your monitoring user to read it. have the cron script run once a minute.

2 Add your monitoring user to the same group that the mysql user belongs to. That will allow the user to check the PID file; though as @galaxy mentioned, this is not really a very good approach to the problem you're trying to solve.